# How do I find rows in a database that are not in the expected order?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table with the structure

```
recordNumber: INTEGER (autoincrement)
insertedOn: DATETIME
```

Normally data gets inserted into the table it increments the `recordNumber` and `insertedOn` is always current time.  Normally the following should be true

```
select insertedOn order by recordNumber === select insertedOn order by insertedOn
```

But that's actually not the case the question I have is how do I query the database so I can find the first `recordNumber` that would break the condition.

Comment: First, this probably depends on the specific database.  Second, you are making a mistake if you make assumptions about insertion order being guaranteed in a relational database.  This is why indexes and ORDER BY exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LAG window function, but it depends on the particular database you are using.
If we assume that your increments are by '1', then this is a little more generic:

```
select top 1 *
from YrTbl Ths
where exists (select 1
              from YrTbl Prev
              where Prev.recordNumber+1=Ths.recordNumber
                  and Prev.insertedOn>=Ths.insertedOn
              )
order by Ths.RecordNumber
```

TOP n might work a little differently in your environment; if you are using MySQL you might like to use LIMIT 1 at the end of the query, for example.